# Como obtengo el atributo de otro modelo en django

Tags: python, django

Mis modelos son estos y quiero obtener el atributo costo del modelo programas, necesito el costo del programas para poder insertarlo en el atributo monto del modelo Cursante, según operaciones previas de descuento

```
class programas(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField('Nombres',max_length=50, blank= True)
    horas = models.CharField('Horas',max_length=50, blank= True)
    creditos = models.CharField('Creditos',max_length=50, blank= True)
    costo = models.IntegerField('Costo',max_length=200,blank=False, null=True)

class Cursante(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField('Nombres',max_length=50, blank= True)
    fecha_de_envio=models.DateTimeField('Fecha de envio',default=datetime.now, blank=False)
    apellidos = models.CharField('Apellidos',max_length=50, blank= True)
    telefono = models.CharField('Teléfono',max_length=50, blank= True)
    ci = models.IntegerField('Cédula',max_length=30,blank=False,null=True)

    id_programas=models.ForeignKey(programas,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    id_usuario=models.ForeignKey(Usuario,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

    monto = models.IntegerField('Monto',max_length=150, blank= True, null=True)
```

Comment: Seria importante que compartas la forma en la que has intentado hacerlo, o almenos el resultado de salida que deseas y los datos de entrada que proporcionaras, eso dara suficiente informacion para que se te pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, en Cursante no deberías poner `id_programas`, ni `id_usuario`. debería ser:

```
programa=models.ForeignKey(programas,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
usuario=models.ForeignKey(Usuario,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

porque? porque al relacionar con una FK lo que estas haciendo es vincular el objeto entero, es decir, que una vez tengas el programa relacionado, luego desde una vista puedes hacer:

```
cursante.programa.id  # para conseguir la id del programa relacionado
```

Y por consiguiente puedes hacer

```
cursante.programa.costo  # para conseguir el monto que deseas
```

Teniendo esto último en mente, no te hace falta añadir el campo de monto, porque en caso que modifiques el costo de tu programa, tendrás que estar haciendo siempre las comprobaciones para que ese campo sea el mismo, y es bastante ineficiente.

Otro detalle importante: Django crea automáticamente las ids de los modelos, así que te puedes ahorrar ese atributo ya que se gestiona automáticamente.

Otra mejora en el fecha de envío es usar `auto_now_add=True` en vez de default.

En `Cursante.nombre` deberías ponerlo en singular dado que estás hablando del atributo de UN objeto de esa clase.

En resumen, tu modelo Cursante quedaría así:

```
class Cursante(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50, blank= True)
    fecha_de_envio=models.DateTimeField('Fecha de envio', auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
    apellidos = models.CharField('Apellidos',max_length=50, blank= True)
    telefono = models.CharField('Teléfono',max_length=50, blank= True)
    ci = models.IntegerField('Cédula',max_length=30,blank=False,null=True)

    programa=models.ForeignKey(programas,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    usuario=models.ForeignKey(Usuario,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

> Nota: También deberías quitar el atributo id de programa.

> Para el teléfono te recomiendo mirarte el [siguiente enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130942/whats-the-best-way-to-store-phone-number-in-django-models).

> En programa: Horas, creditos y costo deberías ponerlos como PositiveIntegerfield, así te ahorras hacer la validación de que no sean numeros negativos ni que se pongan caracteres.

Comment: por favor, si esta respuesta te ha sido util y te ha solucionado el problema, por favor márcala como correcta. Así la gente sabrá que te ha solucionado el problema y si ellos se encuentran con lo mismo sabrán cual es la respuesta que necesitan.